# Never shall we die....!

Tags: riddle, knowledge, language, history

> Here now the accounts of the nine pirate lords
>   And one impostor amidst them all
>
> Here now their voice and story
>   And which impostor to die
>
> The first of all is the chief of all
>   Hidden by the songs of death
>
> The second lord brought with him a dove
>   And the largest army of the bunch
>
> The third of such is the most known of such
>   Named by a foreigner to the original one
>
> The fourth lord is cruel and lost
>   And dragged the Titan down to the abyss
>
> The fifth pirate is known as Helen, aged yet classy
>   Some may call her Tethys, others, a hybrid
>
> The sixth one birthed the iron with a feet of clay,
>   Known by the Greeks as horse of superiority
>
> The seventh pirate's a distant relative to Heracles
>   Though in possession by the Roman army
>
> The eighth pirate reigns up not down
>   Don't let its waters deceive its name
>
> The ninth lord reigns down not up
>   The waters describe its name
>
> The tenth pirate may have met with Moses
>   Columbus looked for him but found the third instead
>
> Answer me, yet truthfully
>   Which pirate is to be dead?

*Also a free, bonus -0 points to whoever figures out what the title is referencing*

*Pirate name not needed, just their number. Also tell me the EXACT name of the sea, that's the more important part*

Clue:

> Pirate one is the traitor, but *why*?

Clue #2:

> Homer and sirens, what's that all about?

Clue #3:

> What's a prominent sea surrounding Greece?

Comment: Argghh... suggestions for improvement (if necessary), or ye shall walk the plank! *angrily waves hook*

Comment: title refers to rot13 (ylevpf bs "Ubvfg gur Pbybhef" sebz Cvengrf bs gur Pnevoorna 3) , unless this is too surface a reference ....

Comment: @Kryesec correct! It's somewhat related with the riddle, regarding the Pirate Lords and stuff. If y'all haven't watched the movie, I would advise y'all to do just a little reserach to get some background

Comment: How far into the movie we need to see, because there's a lot to cover :P Would the Pirate Lord meeting participants suffice?

Comment: The only trivia regarding the movie is that there nine pirate lords and what the nine seas are.

Comment: Final hint has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, the first sea, and the imposter is,

> The Aegean Sea

as it was referenced as the Archipelago which in ancient Greek indeed meant Chief Sea. Today we use the term archipelago to reference a set of islands and not the sea around them.

Hidden by songs of death refer to Odysseus sailing in these waters with clever preparation to not be seduced by the sirens and their songs.

Comment: Finally... if you want to delete the old post, please do so/

Comment: You've got the checkmark because you've solved the riddle. I'm suggesting that the bounty be awarded to JoeyDione, because he *did* solve most of the riddle

Comment: I totally agree.

Answer (score 7):

Partial

The nine pirate lords

> appear in *Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End*. The pirates and the seas they control are listed in the [POTC wiki](https://pirates.fandom.com/wiki/Pirate_Lord).

The first of all is the chief of all
Hidden by the songs of death

> A song of death is a [swan song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swan_song). This could refer to **Swansea**, which is not a sea at all so the impostor would be the first pirate lord. Not sure what "chief" would mean in this case, though...

The second lord brought with him a dove
And the largest army of the bunch

> A dove is a symbol of peace, and the **Pacific Ocean** is the largest of all seas. Also, the Pacific is home to North Korea which has the [largest navy in the world](https://nordic.businessinsider.com/biggest-navies-in-the-world-2018-4?r=US&IR=T) by number of ships.

The third of such is the most known of such
Named by a foreigner to the original one

> From #10 we know this is what Columbus found, so **Caribbean Sea**. I suppose the name was given by Europeans, although the word originates from "Carib" which was the name a Caribbean native people called themselves.

The fourth lord is cruel and lost
And dragged the Titan down to the abyss

> This is the **Atlantic Ocean**. *The Cruel Sea* is a book about the Battle of the Atlantic, Atlantis was a lost city, and the Atlantic is the place where the Titanic sank (thanks @dcfyj!).

The fifth pirate is known as Helen, aged yet classy
Some may call her Tethys, others, a hybrid

> ?

The sixth one birthed the iron with a feet of clay,
Known by the Greeks as horse of superiority

> ?

The seventh pirate's a distant relative to Heracles
Though in possession by the Roman army

> ?

The eighth pirate reigns up not down
Don't let it's waters deceive it's name

> ?

The ninth lord reigns down not up
The waters describe it's name

> ?

The tenth pirate may have met with Moses
Columbus looked for him but found the third instead

> Annosz figured out that this is the **Indian Ocean**. Columbus was looking for India, and Moses parted the Red Sea which is a marginal sea of the Indian Ocean.

Comment: added a clue, mate

Comment: another clue added.

Comment: The 4th clue seems like a direct reference to Rot13(gur fvaxvat bs gur Gvgnavp)

Answer (score 6):

```
Here now the accounts of the nine pirate lords  
And one impostor amidst them all

Here now their voice and story  
And which impostor to die

The first of all is the chief of all  
Hidden by the songs of death
```

> Not really sure about that one but I think it is **Oceanus**, the river encircling the world, the father of everything and the limit between the habitable world and the underworld.

```
The second lord brought with him a dove  
And the largest army of the bunch
```

> **Pacific Ocean** found by @Annosz and @jafe
>  The dove is the symbol of peace => pacific and the Pacific Ocean is the biggest one

```
The third of such is the most known of such  
Named by a foreigner to the original one
```

> **Carribean Sea** found by @Annosz and @jafe
>  Was named by europeans and is the most know because of the Pirates of the Carribean.

```
The fourth lord is cruel and lost  
And dragged the Titan down to the abyss
```

> The **Atlantic Ocean** is the host of the bermudas triangle where so many ships has been lost to the sudent tempests. It is also the ocean that engulfed Atlantide, who was named by the greeks after the titan Atlas. But @Annosz said that also but that wasn't a good answer. Sadly, it was the last one I didn't placed anywhere

```
The fifth pirate is known as Helen, aged yet classy  
Some may call her Tethys, others, a hybrid
```

> The **Caspian Sea** is a remnant of the Tethys sea but I can't find a link with Helen

```
The sixth one birthed the iron with a feet of clay,  
Known by the Greeks as horse of superiority
```

> The **Adriatic Sea** was also named Mare Superior in the antiquity, the mare is the female of the horse. It's also adjacent to Yugoslavia who was the hole (feet of clay) of the Iron curtain since it was in the Non-Aligned movement.

```
The seventh pirate's a distant relative to Heracles  
Though in possession by the Roman army
```

> The Pillars of Hercules/Heracles are at the entrance of the **Mediterranean Sea** and the roman empire named it "Mare Nostrum" who translate as "Our Sea"

```
The eighth pirate reigns up not down  
Don't let it's waters deceive it's name
```

> The **Black Sea** has been named by the greeks by the system where color replace cardinal points, black or dark for north, and not because the water is black.

```
The ninth lord reigns down not up  
The waters describe it's name
```

> The **South China Sea** is situated, well, south of China. It's also named the Eastern sea by the vietnamese as it's the sea east of Vietnam, and named the West Philippines Sea by the Philippines, because it's west of the Philippines...

```
The tenth pirate may have met with Moses  
Columbus looked for him but found the third instead
```

> **Indian ocean** found by @Annosz 
>  Columbus searched India but found the carribeans instead and the red sea is parth of the indian ocean.

```
Answer me, yet truthfully  
Which pirate is to be dead?
```

> The first pirate, as lord of **Oceanus**, an ocean that doesn't exist, is the impostor and should be condamned to death

Comment: Everything is right besides the first! Yikes! Think more in the lines of literature *cough* Homer *cough*

Comment: @North Thanks to your hint, I think it's because Ithaca is the the capital-state of the small kingdom ruled by Odysseus. Songs of death represents Sirens, so I assume it may be Strait of Messina which is the imposter?

Comment: @Adib Sirens is correct! Think a liitle bigger....

Comment: The 4th clue seems like a direct reference to Rot13(gur fvaxvat bs gur Gvgnavp)

Answer (score 4):

The answer is

> Pirate Number 5

Explanation:

```
The first of all is the chief of all 
Hidden by the songs of death
```

> The first pirate represents Elizabeth Swann, because she can hear the songs of the pirate since childhood. She was also elected as the Pirate King

```
The second lord brought with him a dove
And the largest army of the bunch
```

> The second pirate represents Ching, because she has the largest pirate army of the seven seas!

```
The third of such is the most known of such
Named by a foreigner to the original one
```

> The third pirate represents Jocard, who was brought in as a slave, but later rose to become a Pirate Lord after killing his master and taking his name

```
The fourth lord is cruel and lost
And dragged the Titan down to the abyss
```

> I think this is Hector Barbossa if we're following the movies series

```
The fifth pirate is known as Helen, aged yet classy
Some may call her Tethys, others, a hybrid
```

> This is the imposter amongst them. Just doesn't fit with the Pirates of the Caribbean story

```
The sixth one birthed the iron with a feet of clay,
Known by the Greeks as horse of superiority
```

> I think this is Jack Sparrow because of the feet of clay reference, but he is sneaky like a Trojan horse

```
The seventh pirate's a distant relative to Heracles
Though in possession by the Roman army
```

> This may be Captaine Chevalle, since he was captured by army.

```
The eighth pirate reigns up not down
Don't let it's waters deceive it's name
```

> This may be Ammand, who reigns the Black Seas, but he is not black.

```
The ninth lord reigns down not up
The waters describe it's name
```

> Definitely sounds like Sumbhajee Angria - King of the Indian Ocean and the water describes his name

```
The tenth pirate may have met with Moses
Columbus looked for him but found the third instead
```

> This may references to Eduardo Villanueva, because he is a pirate of the Italian Seas and Spain!

Comment: Yikes you're relying waaay too much on movie info. There's a reason for putting the linguistics tag on the question.

Comment: Figure out the EXACT seas they rule, that'll help you. I avoided making any references to the movie itself in the clues, the clues actually hint at either the origin of the word or references in history. I should also add the history tag.

Comment: You will need to know which sea/ocean counts as a pirate that the pirate can lord over (i.e. Jack Sparrow is the pirate of the Caribbean sea while Antarctic Ocean isn't one of the nine seas. FYI, Antartica is NOT one of the answers, and I presume that you already know Jack Sparrow is the pirate of the Caribbean Sea since... that's like the title of the movie).

Comment: Clue added, might help

Answer (score 4):

Many sea names were mentioned before, and @jafe even pointed to

> the Wiki page of the *Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End*, where the [9 seas are listed](https://pirates.fandom.com/wiki/Pirate_Lord).

What is different in my solution is that I think

> We need to match these *exact* seas to the riddle, and find the one that is left - the traitor.

The first of all is the chief of all
Hidden by the songs of death

> I think this most obviously refers to the **Black sea**, as black is the color of death.

The second lord brought with him a dove
And the largest army of the bunch

> The dove is the symbol of peace, wich aligns well with the **Pacific Ocean**. Also, it is the largest sea. (Also found by @jafe)

The third of such is the most known of such
Named by a foreigner to the original one

> The tenth pirate hint that this is the sea which was found by Columbus - the **Caribbean Sea**. It is also the most well-known, because of the movies. (Also found by @jafe)

The fourth lord is cruel and lost
And dragged the Titan down to the abyss

> The titan Atlas shares the name with Atlantis, the lost city, which dissapeared in the **Atlantic Ocean** (what a coincidence - also the same name). (Also found by @jafe)

The fifth pirate is known as Helen, aged yet classy
Some may call her Tethys, others, a hybrid

> The Tethys Ocean is the ancestor of the **Mediterranean Sea**, which i think is the most classiest of the seas. Also, the presence of Greace could explain the Helen reference.

The sixth one birthed the iron with a feet of clay,
Known by the Greeks as horse of superiority

> I have to admit, this was the one I had as a leftover from the nine seas - the **Caspian Sea**. The ironworking originated from this are, and the Trojan horse's breed may be Caspian horse.

The seventh pirate's a distant relative to Heracles
Though in possession by the Roman army

> The **Adriatic Sea**, was ruled by the Romans, and it is very close to Greece and the Mediterranean Sea, which can explain the Heracles reference. (Also found by @jafe)

The eighth pirate reigns up not down
Don't let it's waters deceive it's name

> This will mean the **South China Sea**, which has *South* in his name, but is actually on the Northern Hemisphere.

The ninth lord reigns down not up
The waters describe it's name

> I think he is the traitor - the **Dead Sea**, which is not on the list of the nine seas. He reigns down, in the empire of death, and clearly goes very literally with the last question: *"Which pirate is to be dead?"*

The tenth pirate may have met with Moses
Columbus looked for him but found the third instead

> Moses parted the Red Sea, which is part of the **Indian Ocean**. It is also clear that Columbus originally looked for a way to India.

Summing that up:

> The traitor is the ninth lord, the lord of the **Dead Sea** - he shall be dead.

Comment: The first ocean is wrong, think more of ... mythology for the references ;)

Comment: You should probably look at the etymology of the words as well.

Comment: The ones that are right are: second sea, third sea, and the tenth sea is correct.

Comment: Okay, hint hint. Pirate one is the fraud, but *why*?